# C++ Plug-in Version Checking via Function Export

Tags: c++, plugins, dll, versioning, dllexport

I have two DLLs, `Core` and `Extension`.  `Extension` implicitly links `Core` (using Core.lib).  `Extension` is intended to be a plug-in (explicitly linked) into an executable  which also implicitly links `Core`.

`Core` declares a function which is exported in Core.dll (`extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GetCoreVersion()`), which I would also like to export in Extension.dll.

The intended purpose is to compare versions--I want to be able to ensure that the plug-in (Extension) was linked against the same version of Core.dll as the executable.  This check would be performed in the executable, as it explicitly links Extension.dll (via `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`).  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to Extension, which causes the `GetCoreVersion` symbol to be exported:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:_GetCoreVersion");
```

The executable is now able to find the function (via `GetProcAddress("GetCoreVersion")`).